# Select table element after certain text with xpath

Tags: select, xpath, text

[image]

I'm very new to `XPath` and I've been trying to find a way to select text after a node with certain text. In this case I need to select the `td` after the `th` with `'Position Title'` text.
I tried things like this:

```
//th[starts-with(text(), 'Position Title')]//td
```

but it didn't work.
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `XPath` intend to search for `td` which is direct or indirect child of `th`, but actually you need to match `td` which is sibling of `th`

Try this one:

```
//th[text()='Position Title']/following-sibling::td
```